# js: Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, plotly, qtwebengine

I'm working with plotly and pyqt5 (gui development) and when I try download/export the image generated, this message appear:

```
js: Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.
```

I'm using QtWebengine, the next example:

```
import plotly.offline as po
import plotly.graph_objs as go

from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import sys


def show_qt(fig):
    raw_html = '<html><head><meta charset="utf-8" />'
    raw_html += '<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script></head>'
    raw_html += '<body>'
    raw_html += po.plot(fig, include_plotlyjs=False, output_type='div')
    raw_html += '</body></html>'

    fig_view = QWebEngineView()
    # setHtml has a 2MB size limit, need to switch to setUrl on tmp file
    # for large figures.
    fig_view.setHtml(raw_html)
    fig_view.show()
    fig_view.raise_()
    return fig_view


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    fig = go.Figure(data=[{'type': 'scattergl', 'y': [2, 1, 3, 1]}])
    fig_view = show_qt(fig)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a warning that warns that the way to download the image (converting it to bytes) can cause a security error but in this case you can ignore it. If you want to download a file then you must use the downloadRequested signal of the QWebEnginePage:

```
def handle_downloadRequested(item):
    path, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(
        None, "Save File", item.suggestedFileName()
    )
    if path:
        item.setPath(path)
        item.accept()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    fig = go.Figure(data=[{"type": "scattergl", "y": [2, 1, 3, 1]}])
    fig_view = show_qt(fig)
    fig_view.page().profile().downloadRequested.connect(
        handle_downloadRequested
    )
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```